# Nested powershell parameters

Tags: powershell, parameters, process

In a powershell script I need to start the process powershell and tell it to run the script foo.ps1 like so:

```
start-process powershell C:\foodir\foo.ps1
```

But I ran into problems when I needed the script foo to be run with parameters.  I tried some code like this:

```
start-process powershell (C:\foodir\foo.ps1 -paramforfoo test)
```

but this simply freezes the script when it gets to this line and throws no errors.  I think it is trying to pass the parameter test to the powershell process and not to the script foo.  How can I run this script with parameters?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651223/powershell-start-process-and-cmdline-switches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using quotes to collect your command. E.g.

```
Start-Process powershell ".\Untitled3.ps1 -testparam 'hello world'"
```