# Verb RunAs in a Start-Process Powershell command causes an error

Tags: powershell, runas

If I run the following command in a Poweshell script file ($cmd refers to some executable):

```
Start-Process -FilePath $cmd -Verb RunAs Powershell
```

Then it executes OK

But if I slightly modify it:

```
Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath $cmd -Verb RunAs Powershell
```

Or like this:

```
Start-Process -FilePath $cmd -ArgumentList @("status") -Verb RunAs Powershell
```

... then the command fails with the following error message:

> Start-Process : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified
>   named parameters.

I wonder why this format is not accepted and how should I modify the command to both specify an argument list and option "-Verb RunAs..."

Comment: Guessing that `-NoNewWindow` and `-Verb RunAs` cannot be combined since you can elevate the session currently used. Going to check and see if that is true. I read that they are [incompatible](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/0ea76b46-8396-43e5-8caa-1cc929a74b8a/are-these-parameters-incompatibles?forum=winserverpowershell)

Comment: Oh I see, that is why! Thanks for the clarification. I could accept it as an answer if you rewrite your observation as an answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Guessing that `-NoNewWindow` and `-Verb RunAs` cannot be combined since you can't elevate the session currently used.

Upon futher investigation you are not the only one to look into this. I read that they are incompatible [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/0ea76b46-8396-43e5-8caa-1cc929a74b8a/are-these-parameters-incompatibles?forum=winserverpowershell)

Depending on your motivation for running it like this you could just hide the window

```
Start-Process "powershell" -Verb "runas" -WindowStyle hidden
```

You can also look into [`PSSession`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34619486/enter-pssession-invoke-command-when-to-use) which can handle this type of thing as well. That could start an interactive session in the same window.

Comment: Bingo! In fact this is quite logical. It would be strange if it was possible to elevate permissions without leaving a session represented by current window.

Comment: @VagifAbilov So what's the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651223/powershell-start-process-and-cmdline-switches) helps you out:

```
$cmd = 'powershell.exe'
$arguments = "-NoLogo -NoProfile -WindowStyle Maximized"
Start-Process $cmd $arguments -Verb runAs
```

Another example from [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/132e170f-e3e8-4178-9454-e37bfccd39ea/startprocess-verb-runas-credential):

```
Start-Process powershell -Credential mydomain\mydomainAdmin -ArgumentList '-noprofile -command &{Start-Process notepad -verb runas}'
```

Can you try it with your program and arguments and see how it goes?

Comment: It goes fine but it's not what I am after. I want to be able to pass "-NoNewWindow" option, and for some reasons I can't combine it with the Verb. The same goes for ArgumentList option. I am trying to understand why they can't be combined.