# How to correctly escape spaces and backslashes in command line arguments?

Tags: powershell, command-line, arguments, escaping

I had some issues passing an array of strings to a command in PowerShell, so I'm debugging my script. I'm using the *EchoArgs.exe* program found in the [PowerShell Community Extension Project (PSCX)](http://pscx.codeplex.com/).
If I execute this script:

```
Import-Module Pscx
cls

$thisOne = 'this_one\';
$secondOne = 'second one\';
$lastOne = 'last_one'

$args = $thisOne `
    , "the $secondOne" `
    , "the_$lastOne"


EchoArgs $args
```

I get this result:

```
Arg 0 is <this_one\>
Arg 1 is <the second one" the_last_one>

Command line:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerShell Community Extensions\Pscx3\Pscx\Apps\EchoArgs.exe"  this_one\ "the second one\" the_last_one
```

It seems that if a string contains spaces, the last backslash escapes the double quote. In fact all seems working if I escape only that backslash:

```
Import-Module Pscx
cls

$thisOne = 'this_one\';
$secondOne = 'second one\\';
$lastOne = 'last_one'

$args = $thisOne `
    , "the $secondOne" `
    , "the_$lastOne"


EchoArgs $args
```

with this result:

```
Arg 0 is <this_one\>
Arg 1 is <the second one\>
Arg 2 is <the_last_one>

Command line:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerShell Community Extensions\Pscx3\Pscx\Apps\EchoArgs.exe"  this_one\ "the second one\\" the_last_one
```

Is there a "smart" way in PowerShell (i.e. a cmdlet) to escape any string in order to avoid such issues?

Comment: What about using single quotes in your PS Script? So `$args = 'this_one', '"the second one"', 'the_last_one'`

Comment: You are right, but I have to use variables in my array strings like `$args = "$thisOne"` and so on.

Comment: I've just updated the code snippets. Thanks

Comment: sidenote: don't use `$args`, it's an automatic variable

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Start-Process` instead.  It has an `$Arguments` parameter that would suit this better.

See here:  [PowerShell - Start-Process and Cmdline Switches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651223/powershell-start-process-and-cmdline-switches)