# How to utilize powershell to open an application with a command?

Tags: powershell

Is there a command that exists that will open any application from PowerShell?

When typing in "notepad", this will open Microsoft Notepad. However, other applications do not seem to open this way.

Comment: Look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651223/powershell-start-process-and-cmdline-switches

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Notepad runs in this way not because of any Powershell magic, but because `notepad.exe` exists in one of the directories specified in your `$env:PATH` environment variable. The system behaves the same as when using `cmd.exe` (Command Prompt) in this regard.

You can start any application by specifying the full path to its executable: `C:\Program Files\FileZilla FTP Client\filezilla.exe`. You can optionally use `Start-Process` with the EXE if you want to capture a reference to the executable to gain more control over it from Powershell.

Comment: Thanks @alroc, this works great, though is there something I could use to pipe the results? This might require another question to be posted.

Comment: @JDavila that depends on what those "results" are, what the app is, and how the output is generated. You should open a new question.

Comment: Well, am trying to display results from a log, specifically, certain columns CSV format.

Comment: You're not making it any clearer. Post a new question for this.

Answer (score 17):

```
Start-Process -FilePath "path.exe"
```

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old thread, but if you are trying to open a file you can do it like this

```
& .\filename.ext
```

It will use the standard program to open the file

Comment: This is using Windows cmd shell. Prepend this with start this works!

Answer (score 6):

`Start-Process` is the commandlet you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest method that I know of is using the AppId of the application:

1. Open powershell as Administrator

   [image]
2. See all the App-IDs via this command

   ```
   Get-StartApps
   ```
3. Note the AppID of app you want to open

   [image]

   in our case we have to open VoiceRecoder
4. Finally, open Voice Recorder via AppId

   ```
   explorer shell:appsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsSoundRecorder_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
   ```

*AppIds are mostly the same between systems*

Answer (score -1):

This same PowerShell script can be put in a shortcut.
I right-clicked on an empty spot on my desktop and then clicked New => Shortcut
and pasted:
explorer shell:appsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsAlarms_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
and named the shortcut "Clock"
Now I can start the Clock app with the shortcut.
No need for Powershell or pinning another icon on my Taskbar.